# How to import MYSQL Dump into Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, putty, amazon-rds

I just logged into my EC2 via Putty on Windows and I got into my RDS instance and into one database I had created. Then I try to import a SQL dump from my machine with the following code which results into an error.

```
    mysql> source C:\Users\guru\Downloads\latest.sql;
    ERROR:
    Unknown command '\U'.
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source C:\Users' at line 1
    ERROR:
    Unknown command '\D'.
    ERROR:
    Unknown command '\l'.
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uru\Downloads\latest.sql' at line 1
```

The file exists in my Windows machine. Please help me resolve the error.

Comment: You need to upload the file first. That file exists on your local machine, but not your ec2 instance. Try WinSCP.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can import a mysql dump straight from my local machine?

Comment: Yes, but you need a mysql client on your local machine to do it. This is probably going to be slower, there will be more latency between each statement.

Comment: I would also recommend using Mysql Workbench (http://wb.mysql.com) to do imports and exports to/from RDS. As Hyper Anthony mentioned, it's going to get pricy and slow as a backup solution, Snapshots + InnoDB for point-in-time restore works best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a very simple and user friendly solution: Downloaded SQLyog https://www.webyog.com and fed in my ssh details for my ec2 and my MYSQL log in details. I ended up accessing a my database using this GUI tool that has all the options for importing and exporting data as easy as on localhost/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3):

As datasage mentioned, you would probably be better off working from your EC2 -> RDS instances.  If you really want to work from your local machine, though:

- Install MySQL for Windows: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
- Add the parent directory of mysql.exe (the mysql command line tool) to your path environment variable.

Try the following in the command prompt.  You could use powershell also, but you would need to wrap this statement in `cmd /c "mysql etc..."` because powershell handles redirection a little differently.

> mysql -u myUser --password=myPass -h rdsEndpoint myDB < C:\Users\guru\Downloads\latest.sql

This procedure would also be useful to know if you have need for a Windows EC2 instance.

As an aside: extracting data from RDS to your local machine can get pricey, especially as your database grows.  If you're just doing this as a backup solution, then you may want to look into [Snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html) or automated backups.  If you are doing this to replicate your RDS environment you could also transfer your data directly from RDS to your EC2 instances, [which is free if both instances are in the same availability zone](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/#DataTransfer).

Comment: Thanks for the info. So I get charged when I mysqldump my data?

Comment: Depends on where it goes, but yeah that would fall under "Data Export" in their pricing page that I linked above.  Exporting to EC2 is much cheaper (and situationally free, minus the cost of the instance) than exporting to your local machine.

Comment: Although this answer is a little Windows-centric, the command also works fine on Linux (any POSIX with mysql client installed)   `mysql -u username -p -h RDS_endpoint DB_name < backup.sql`